# Не работает strtotime() с полученными датами

Tags: php, функции, дата, время, datetime

Я пытаюсь получить в функции номер текущей недели и года, а затем преобразовать его в формат с русским языком, для чего и добавил перевод месяцев и дней, чтобы выводилось так:

`Понедельник, 25 ноября`

Теперь я хочу, чтобы к полученному формату даты можно было прибавлять или отнимать дни, и использую strtotime(), но у меня не получается. Как в return вывести + 1 день от данного формата? Надеюсь, что доступно описал проблему.

Моя функция:

```
    function thatWeekMon() {
    $week_number = date("W"); 
    $year = date("Y");

    $months = [
        1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
        5 => 'Мая',    6 => 'Июня',    7 => 'Июля',  8 => 'Августа',
        9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'
    ];

    $days = ["Sunday" => "Воскресенье", "Monday" => "Понедельник", "Tuesday" => "Вторник", "Wednesday" => "Среда", "Thursday" => "Четверг", "Friday" => "Пятница", "Saturday" => "Суббота"];

    $d = strtotime("+1 days");

    $first_day = $days[date('l', ($week_number-1) * 7 * 86400 + strtotime('1/1/' . $year) - date('w', strtotime('1/1/' . $year)) * 86400 + 86400)];

    $first_day1 = date('d', ($week_number-1) * 7 * 86400 + strtotime('1/1/' . $year) - date('w', strtotime('1/1/' . $year)) * 86400 + 86400);

    $first_day2 = $months[date('m', ($week_number-1) * 7 * 86400 + strtotime('1/1/' . $year) - date('w', strtotime('1/1/' . $year)) * 86400 + 86400)];

    return date("$first_day, $first_day1 $first_day2", $d);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело или как переписать ее?

Comment: храните как была, к ней и прибавляйте, а показывайте на русском

Comment: Что за дичь. Одной строкой день прибавляется `echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));`

Comment: @splash58 , не помогает

Comment: Проще использовать библиотеку типа Carbon, установив локаль на русскую: setlocale(LC_TIME,'ru_RU'); Carbon::setLocale(‘ru’); Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%A, %d. %B %Y'); Это для вывода строкой, а работать нужно с Carbon::now() объектом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае сработал такой вариант:

```
function beed($add=0) {

    $months = [
        1 => 'Января', 2 => 'Февраля', 3 => 'Марта', 4 => 'Апреля',
        5 => 'Мая',    6 => 'Июня',    7 => 'Июля',  8 => 'Августа',
        9 => 'Сентября', 10 => 'Октября', 11 => 'Ноября', 12 => 'Декабря'];

    $days = ["Sunday" => "Воскресенье", "Monday" => "Понедельник", "Tuesday" => "Вторник", "Wednesday" => "Среда", "Thursday" => "Четверг", "Friday" => "Пятница", "Saturday" => "Суббота"];

    $r = date('l');
    $t = $days[date('l', strtotime("Monday +$add days"))];

    $r1 = date('d');
    $t1 = date('d', strtotime("Monday +$add days"));

    $r2 = date('m');
    $t2 = $months[date('m', strtotime("Monday +$add days"))];

    return date("$t, $t1 $t2");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дату на русском языке не сможет распарсить ни `date()`, ни `DateTime::createFromFormat()`, поэтому вам сначала нужно прибавить нужное количество дней, а потом уже переводить дату на другой язык. Вы можете это сделать, например, с помощью метода `add()` класса [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php):

```php
$date = new DateTime('2019-11-25');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$result = $date->format('l, d F'); // Tuesday, 26 November
```

Подробная информация в документации:

- [DateTime::add](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.add.php)
- [DateInterval::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.construct.php)